# ColdFusion shopping cart

Tags: coldfusion, shopping-cart

Update: I'm rewriting with all my code for each page as well as my error message... keep in mind I am very new and honestly don't know some of this code...

productlist.cfm 1st page: (hard coded product list code built from select statement)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/week8/assignments/scripts/jbrown.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/week8/assignments/scripts/jbrown2.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" ></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <title>Scuba Diving is Fun!</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
<cfquery name = "getlist" datasource="jeb48_shoppingcart">
 SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductQty, ProductPrice, ProductDescription, ProductPhoto
 FROM Products;
</cfquery>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"><b>Product Photo</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><b>Product ID</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><b>Product Name</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><b>Quantity in Inventory</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><b>Product Description</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><b>Unit Price</b></div>
          </div !--row> 
          <cfoutput query ="getlist"> 
          <div class="row  equallist">
            <div class="col-md-2">#getlist.ProductPhoto#</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">#getlist.ProductID#</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">#getlist.ProductName#</div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><div style="text-align:center">#getlist.ProductQty#</div></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><div style="text-align:left">#getlist.ProductDescription#</div></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><div style="text-align:left">#DollarFormat(getlist.ProductPrice)#
            <cfif #getlist.ProductQty# gt 0>
            <br><a href = "scart.cfm?productid=#getlist.productid#&qty=1&action=add">Add to Cart</a>
            <cfelse>
            <br>Out of Stock!
            </cfif>
</div></div>
          </div !--row>
          </cfoutput>
        </div !--container>
   </body>
</html>
```

scart.cfm Page 2: This is the page I'm having trouble with... I know my code is messed up but I do not know how to fix it... the error I'm getting is on this page... the error is "Parameter validation error for the ARRAYAPPEND function." I'm trying to build a cart based on the link in the previous page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/week8/assignments/scripts/jbrown.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://students.uwf.edu/jeb48/week8/assignments/scripts/jbrown2.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" ></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <title>Scuba Diving is Fun!</title>
</head>
<body>


        <div class="container">
        <h3><center>Your Shopping Cart</center></h3>            
        <cfparam name="url.productid" default="">
        <cfparam name="url.qty" default="">
        <cfquery name = "getCartItem" datasource="jeb48_shoppingcart">
           SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductQty, ProductPrice, ProductDescription, ProductPhoto
           FROM Products
           WHERE ProductID = #url.productid#;
        </cfquery>

        <cfset arrShoppingCart = arrayNew(1) />
        <cfparam name="session.cart" default="arrayNew()">
        <cfset arrayAppend( "session.cart", structNew() )>
        < cfset session.cart = arrayNew(1) >
        < cfset thisCartItem = arraylen( session.cart )>
        <cfset arrayAppend( session.cart, structNew() )>
        < cfset thisCartItem = arraylen( session.cart )>
        < cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].itemID = url.productid>
        < cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].quantity = url.qty>
</body>
</html>
```

application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent> 
<cfset this.name = "jeb48SC"> 
<cfset this.datasource = "jeb48_shoppingcart"> 
<cfset this.loginstorage="Session"> 
<cfset this.sessionmanagement="Yes"> 
<cfset this.sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,0,45,0)#"> 
</cfcomponent>
```

Once I get this working I can begin working on getting the output built... thanks for taking a look.

Comment: As you're new to CF you might want to post this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for some feedback - I see at least 3 things most experience ColdFusion developers would do differently

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help. I will check on this and mark an answer

Comment: +1 to duncan's suggestion. For example, your current query leaves the database vulnerable to sql injection. It is very important to use `cfqueryparam` on ALL variable query parameters. One of its many benefits is protection against standard sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of the question have significantly changed, so editing my answer.

---

```
  1:  <cfset arrShoppingCart = arrayNew(1) />
  2:  <cfparam name="session.cart" default="arrayNew()">
  3:  <cfset arrayAppend( "session.cart", structNew() )>
  4:  < cfset session.cart = arrayNew(1) >
  5:  < cfset thisCartItem = arraylen( session.cart )>
  6:  <cfset arrayAppend( session.cart, structNew() )>
  7:  < cfset thisCartItem = arraylen( session.cart )>
  8:  < cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].itemID = url.productid>
  9:  < cfset session.cart[thisCartItem].quantity = url.qty>
```

There are a few problems with this code. I'll ignore the spaces after some opening brackets, you're clearly experimenting and canceling out some experiments.

- On line 2, you're not creating an array, you're creating a string with the default value of `"ArrayNew()"`. You need to add hashes around each end. `"#ArrayNew()#"`.
- On line 3, you have the array name quoted, which is invalid. Most cold fusion functions that require a variable name, want it unquoted. Some exceptions are `StructkeyExists()` and `isDefined()`, which serve similar purposes. They check if a variable exists so they ask for the variable name as a string, rather than raw.
- Line 4, this is how you properly set an array. Good Job. The only thing is every time someone visits this page, this happens. This line should be when a session is first initiated and it should go something like this `<cfif not isDefined("session.cart")><cfset session.cart=ArrayNew(1)></cfif>`.
- As I said before, you need to maintain data types across your application. One quick fix is to address your code problems and then create a page that has nothing but this `<Cfset structclear(session)>`. That gets rid of all your old session data.
- You're on the right track after this. It can be tough when you're trying to debug something that you don't (yet!) understand several aspects of, but you'll get it.

---

Okay something else we need to talk about. You're new to CF? That's great, time to start an important habit early.

**Any Time** you're using a `#variable#` in a query, use a tag called `<cfqueryparam`. There's a mischievious thing called SQL injection, where a user can modify a url to cause havoc on the website. This tag is your primary defense against this

(There are occasions where some people don't feel it's necessary but you really cannot over-param your variables and as you're new, it's better to be safe than sorry).

Suppose I'm on `scart.cfm?productID=7`. If I change the url to `scart.cfm?productID=7; DROP TABLE Products`, your products table disappears. Or maybe I just want cheap goodies. `scart.cfm?productID=7; UPDATE Products SET PRICE = 1` (I'd have to guess at column names here), but I could reset all your product prices.

Further CFQueryParam makes your queries slightly faster, and one of my favorite parts, is that when you provide the type, it handles the quoting for you.

Adobe was a bit silly when designing the tag and it's a little long-winded, but you get used to it.

You query above should look like this:

```
   <cfquery name = "getCartItem" datasource="jeb48_shoppingcart">
       SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductQty, ProductPrice, ProductDescription, ProductPhoto
       FROM Products
       WHERE ProductID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.productID#">
    </cfquery>
```

Oh, because you're using `this.datasource` in `application.cfc`, providing a datasource here is not necessary. so your queries can just look like, which makaes your application more mobile.

```
<cfquery name="..."> or <cfquery> for queries where name isn't useful.
```

If you ever find yourself using additional datasources, you can store their names in the request scope, and then you can reference them like `datasource="#request.db1#"` or `#request.db2#'`, etc. There are some applications people have designed that might have particular users using different databases so they have setups like `#session.db#`.

If I was searching for something by say a string value, the where could look like this `WHERE ProductID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.productName#'>`

See, the tag takes care of the quoting, and it lets other developers know your data types at a glance.

---

In the future, please provide more of the error.

From what you've shown, it looks like either:

- A `cfparam` declares `session.sCartItems` somewhere, probably as a basic string. (`<cfparam name="session.sCartItems" default="">` which basically just says, "If not defined, define it". In other words, a `cfparam` on a variable will make an isDefined() check pass.
- In development, you've formerly declared session.sCartItems as a string, and that action is still alive. If that is the case, the not-isDefined() check fails, and the variable is not re-set as an array.

You should resolve the source of this problem. Data types of variables should remain consistent across your application, otherwise you will always constantly be trying to check data types.

However, changing this should bandaid-fix your problem.

```
<cfif not isDefined("session.scartItems")>
```

to:

```
<cfif not isDefined("session.scartItems") or not isArray(session.sCartItems)>
```

The way this is works is if your variable is not defined, the check stops there. If you variable is defined, the check continues to verify that it is an array.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message. I can post my code for all pages if it will help. I just didn't want to post a lot of unnecessary text.

Comment: @JasonBrown Yes please actually, append the error to your original question via an edit.

Comment: Wow this it's awesome. Thank you for such a great explanation. I will be working on this today.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why is session.scart in quotes in this section of line 4? <cfif not isDefined("session.scart")>

Comment: Also, should the session name in <cfif not isDefined("session.scart")> match the rest of the session names? This line is session.scart, the rest are session.cart? Again, this could be a stupid question, just curious.

Comment: After changing the session name to consistant session.scart and making the changes, I got an error "Parameter validation error for function ARRAYNEW. 
The function takes 1 parameter. "

After looking up the error I had to change all the ArrayNew() to Array(1), some were mismatched.

Comment: Yes you're right about session.scart, that was my typo, apologies. ACF does require an argument for ArrayNew(), like ArrayNew(1). How are things working now? Also, I updated my post to fix the scart typo you caught. @JasonBrown

Comment: No errors with the code. Now i have to dive into how to accept inputs from productlist page and actually build the cart list and display the info in the session

Comment: @JasonBrown Well then this is solved. Make sure that any future questions you ask are asked separately. Stack's network of sites operates on a one-question-per-topic format :) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you again for your awesome help, I tried upping the vote for your answer but I couldn't just yet.